# Maven system properties with spaces - Ubuntu wrapper breaks

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I'm trying to pass system properties like this to maven

```
mvn install -Dmy.property="foo bar"
```

With the Ubuntu package wrapper in /usr/bin/mvn, this breaks - somehow the command line gets interpreted as if `-Dmy.property=foo` and `bar`  are separate arguments.

The culprit appears to be something in the wrapper script - somehow, the `$@` in the command `/usr/share/maven2/bin/mvn $@` is re-splitting the command line arguments and mishandling the quotes.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I would try this: add quotes around the whole -D part and put a backslash before the existing quotes?

Comment: tried `"-Dmy.property=\"foo bar\"" ` with same result